# Are email headers encrypted if using secure SMTP with TLS?

Tags: mailgun, nodemailer

I'm using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) to send transactional email from a web application. I have set `secure=true` when I create the [SMTP transport](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/) which means:

> secure – if true the connection will use TLS when connecting to server. If false (the default) then TLS is used if server supports the STARTTLS extension. In most cases set this value to true if you are connecting to port 465.

For email address confirmation and password reset emails, I add the token to the email header as `X-Email-Token` to make it easier to test (can just get the value from the header rather than parse the body of the email). Could a mail server that can't read the body of the message read this header field?

Comment: The correct answer is that all mail servers can read both the body AND headers of all emails sent. This `secure` property only applies to the request of the SMTP client (nodemailer) to the SMTP server (mailgun), from there mailgun delivers the email to the respective mail server in the clear. 

**tl;dr** without GPG email is not a secure communication channel but it's usually good enough for things like password reset links and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could a mail server that can't read the body of the message read this header field?

**Misconception alert**: The `secure=true` option and/or the use of SSL (now obsolete) or TLS to secure e-mail transmission will only secure the communication between the SMTP client and the SMTP server from connection eavesdroppers for that specific connection.

- The receiving SMTP server is not necessarily the final recipient's email server.
- The recieving SMTP server is capable of forwarding the message on to another SMTP server *without* using TLS.
- The receiving SMTP server could be malicious (e.g. in case someone planted fraudulent DNS MX records) and can read the message contents and do something nefarious with the information contained within.

Given this - TLS does not  provide any kind of "real" e-mail message encryption. SMTP is still the e-mail equivalent of writing messages on postcards without envelopes.

By analogy: using TLS with SMTP is like you driving from your home to an outbound mailbox in the street in a creepy van with tinted-windows, but you put a naked postcard into the mailbox - which means anyone at the postal-service and beyond can still read the message - but at least no-one in the street could read the message while you drove it to the outbound mailbox.

Regarding the distinction between Headers and Body:

An MTA (Mail Transfer Agent, i.e. a mail server) *will* be able to read the message body **and** the message headers. In SMTP there is no real distinction between them and TLS is completely blind to all of this as it's only concerned with protecting arbitrary byte streams.

TLS only provides transport-level security, which is the connection *between* MTA hosts - it doesn't stop an MTA from reading the email. For that you need proper message encryption such as PGP or S/MIME and the recipient's public key.

<sup>Opinionated rant: for the effort Google and other Internet companies put into securing the web, it's surprising that there's no real push to secure e-mail. It would not be hard for major e-mail providers like Office 365, Gmail, Outlook.com and others to provide for, at least, message signing (this could be done painlessly by providing message signing provided emails are sent through their own outbound SMTP servers and the user has two-factor auth). The same companies are also capable of setting up a good PKI for the distribution of public-keys. Message signing would pretty much eliminate spam from trusted domain-names overnight, so this is somewhat embarrassing for our species that we still have this problem.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I guess putting the token in the header as well as the body is no-less-secure than putting it in the body. So this is just a risk most applications take by using email as a secure side-channel for proving identity.

Comment: @mwakerman **E-mail does *not* prove identity** - at the most it can prove access to (not even ownership!) the mailbox associated with a particular address, but that's it. It is very difficult to *prove* identity over the Internet in an automated fashion. The best approach will use some form of PKI with nationally-recognised identity providers, some countries have it (e.g. Iceland) but larger countries like the US and UK don't have anything like it (due to either paranoid citizenry, or just internal incompetence)

Comment: I commend the strictness of your definitions but a vast majority of applications treat access to a mailbox associated with an account's address as a form of identification. Ideally, you throw in some security questions or good 2FA implementation but I'm not talking fingerprints and DNA level of identification when I used the word.

Comment: @mwakerman Yes, and that's okay when you look at what they're attempting to do: verify that an e-mail address is valid and works. If you look closely you'll see that it is *not* to verify personal identity at all - just that an e-mail address works. I recommend you read-up on what exactly "Identity" means in a security system.

Comment: I disagree. It's not just checking that an email address is "valid and works". Password resets are very (very!) often implemented via a single-use token sent via email. If trusting someone with access to an email account to change credentials isn't "identification" then I don't know what is.

Comment: @mwakerman "Password resets are very (very!) often implemented via a single-use token sent via email" - this is why when security matters you use TFA.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different use case for encryption than you're thinking of. With SSL/TLS, both you and the server can read the entire message (including the headers), but somebody who is between you and the server can't.

If you want the server to not be able to read the message, you instead need to use something like GPG, and you're correct that you can't encrypt the headers that way or the server won't be able to deliver the message.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken thinking even the body was encrypted. But this is a web application's password reset functionality so I'm not going down the path of GPG.